# passing parameter without anonymous function in javascript

Tags: function, anonymous

In addeventlistener we must use anonymous function for passing parameter
for example

```
body.addeventlistener('click,function(){myfunc(str)});
```

why can't we use normal function for passing parameter??
for example

```
body.addeventlistener('click,myfunc(str));
function myfunc(str)
{
alert(str);
}
```

why does not this code work?